# Frontispiece (really)

Tags: typography

Is there a “natural” way (i.e., compatible with the existence of \frontmatter, \maketitle etc.) to produce a [half title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_title) and a [frontispiece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_frontispiece) for a book being typeset in LaTeX? Here, by “frontispiece” I actually mean the page facing the title page.

<sub>By “frontispiece” I do not mean the title page, even though in some Romance languages (among which mine) it is called something similar, hence some false positives searching in this website.</sub>

Comment: Do you want the outer cover page?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks: I have clarified better what I need.

Comment: I guess https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation would be the most natural way, the customizing section.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I checked that, but, if I am not missing something, it just suggests ways to customise the title page, while I need those further, earlier pages, before the title page.

Comment: `\maketitle` is just for proofs. When you want a real title page (in a generic sense), you have to do it by hand. For a series of books one can define a suitable `\maketitle` that uses the provided metadata.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you call a page half-title or frontispiece or something, it is a page with some special text on it.

Comment: That's right, @Johannes_B, but not terribly helpful. The same holds for title pages, tables of contents, indexes and so one, yet there are specialised commands and packages for those. I just wondered if something analogous exists for those special pre-title-page pages.

Comment: No, there are not. Just as egreg said, do it by hand. Please see also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: Thanks, @Johannes_B. Would the be the same page you already mentioned and that, as I told you, I already had checked? If you are positive that there are absolutely no specialised commands or packages for this kind of pages, that in itself would be a useful answer that I'd upvote.

Comment: Yes, it would be the same page, but for desktop view. Oh wait, i already gave the desktop (not mobile) link earlier. It is a mystery to me that you do not see the content. Out of curiosity, do you see anything here? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: Saying *there are none, do it by hand* is not really an answer. But jhor already gave an answer, you could ask in a comment if there are no commands, he will probably edit the question. We also have http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 The question could as well be *how to define one special page* either for title, or abstract, or ... When it comes to special stuff like that, it is about formatting, there is no real point in having an interface.

Comment: For me, there is always thinking about [template confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion). There is one CV template where you can input about 5 different personal things (like email and twitter) and the sorting is fixed. People always ask to add support for Facebook and Instagram or googleScholar etc. One could define an interface for the user to input what they like/need, but the code would be soooo huge compared to just add the things manually. It is much cleaner, and much simpler.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I was cofusing you with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443395/how-to-change-the-font-type-for-title-page-only?noredirect=1#comment1112920_443395 that thread. Sorry. Nevermind my first comment from a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here as a dummy example, with a very simplistic cover/title page:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\savegeometry{generalgeometry} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%COVERPAGE
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\newgeometry{a4paper,margin=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{minipage}[t][0.9\textheight]{\linewidth}
\centering
\strut\vfill
{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily MY TITLE \par}
\vfill
{\Large \scshape Firtname  Lastname\par}
\vfill\strut
\end{minipage}
\clearpage
%FRONTISPIECE
\begin{center}
\strut\vfill
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{frontispiece}
\vfill\strut
\end{center}
\clearpage
%TITLE PAGE
\begin{minipage}[t][0.9\textheight]{\linewidth}
\centering
\strut\vfill
{\Huge \bfseries \sffamily MY TITLE \par}
\vfill
{\Large \scshape Firstname  Lastname\par}
\vfill\strut
\end{minipage}
\cleardoublepage
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\restoregeometry
\pagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\textsc{Contents}}{\textsc{Contents}}

\mainmatter
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

With results in:
[image]

[A PDF version on the web](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snonuus5fh6d8c9/frontispiece.pdf?dl=0) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/snonuus5fh6d8c9/frontispiece.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a solid example to start from. As egreg and @Johannes_B explain in the comment to the question, and you confirm by this fine example, the lesson is that to I have to compose things as I need them, and this is comforting, I like to tinker with LaTeX; I was only afraid that I was ignoring some fundamental package specifically for what I need (it wouldn't make sense to re-invent the machinery to create an index, say).

Answer (score 2):

What's your Class of choice?

It happens that KOMA-Script provides exactly that:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\frontispiece{My text}
\title{The Book}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a handmade title, fontispiece and halt-title pages with memoir, but the bonus is that sometimes the frontispiece image deserves a reference in the list of figures:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\title{The Nice Book Title}
\author{Nice Clever Author}
\date{\today} 


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% ------ The title page ----- 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{\baselineskip}
\vfill
\hbox{%
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
\rule{1pt}{\textheight}
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth}%
\parbox[b]{0.75\textwidth}{
\vbox{%
\vspace{0.08\textheight}
{\noindent\HUGE\bfseries\thetitle}\\[2\baselineskip]
{\Large\itshape The also nice subtitle}\\[4\baselineskip]
{\Large\scshape\theauthor}\par
\vspace{0.5\textheight}
{\noindent The Publisher} \hfill \thedate\\[2\baselineskip]}}}
\vfill
% ---------------------------------

\pagebreak

% ------ The frontispiece page ----- 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cftlocalchange{lof}{6em}{5em} 
{\centering\makebox[0pt]{\includegraphics[height=.99\textheight]{example-image-9x16}}\par}
\cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{Sgraffito of John Milton}{frontispiece}
\cftlocalchange{lof}{1.55em}{2.55em} % return to normal settings
% ---------------------------------

\pagebreak

% ------ The halt-title page ----- 
\thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{1}
\vspace*{.3\textheight}{\huge\bfseries\thetitle}\par
\vspace*{.05\textheight}{\Large\scshape\theauthor}\vfill\pagebreak
% ---------------------------------

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{The begining} 
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image A}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[5-10]

\chapter{The end}
\lipsum[11-14]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image B}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[15-16]
\end{document}
```