# how to change the font type for title page only?

Tags: fonts

I use (Times new roman) for all my report by using `\usepackage{times}` but I need to change title page only to normal latex font type. how could do that?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: the website page is empty

Comment: No, it is not empty.

Comment: in the front page in the web is written (The latest reviewed version was checked on 8 May 2018. There are template/file changes awaiting review.) and the last page is empty

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation what do you see here?

Answer (score 4):

You should use package `mathptmx` or `newtx` instead of `times`. However,
changing the font for the titlepage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\title{Some text for the title}
\author{Me and others}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
\maketitle
\endgroup

\section{foo}
bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use \usepackage{newtxtext} \usepackage{newtxmath} but unfortunately it isn't work for me.

Comment: Is there any command i can use in title page only to change its font, without affect the whole text font {new time roman} that used by \usepackage{times}

Comment: Do you want to change the font for the title text or for everything on the title page (atite, author, date)?

Comment: I need to change everything on the title page, i would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: I already showed you in my example how the title page can be set with Latin modern